# python scheduled independent threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to create a Daemon who runs shell commands , gets results and rerun them again when they're over . Multiple shell commands at the same time will be running so every command has to be independent from the other. I've decided to use Python threading. The code I wrote may work but it seems to me really unelegant , do you know how to achieve it in a better and elegant way?

BTW: in this example I'm running 2 commands , I'd like to run many commands at the same time.

```
import time
from daemon import runner
import threading

class Daemonity():

  def __init__(self):
      self.stdin_path = '/dev/null'
      self.stdout_path = '/dev/tty'
      self.stderr_path = '/dev/tty'
      self.pidfile_path =  '/tmp/daemonity.pid'
      self.pidfile_timeout = 5

 def my_function(count, host):
     # this is an example function that will execute a ping command on the shell
     cmd_run = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c", count, host],
                                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
                              )


 def run(self):

      t1 = threading.Thread(name="ping", target=my_function, args=("5", "8.8.8.8"))
      t1.daemon = True
      t1.start()

      t2 = threading.Thread(name="ping2", target=my_function, rgs=("5", "8.8.4.4") )
      t2.daemon = True
      t2.start()


      while True:
          time.sleep(2)

          if not t1.isAlive():
              print "start thread t1"
              t1 = threading.Thread(name="ping", target=my_function, rgs=("5", "8.8.8.8"))
              t1.daemon = True
              t1.start()

          if not t2.isAlive():
              print "start thread t2"
              t2 = threading.Thread(name="ping2", target=my_function, rgs=("5", "8.8.4.4") )
              t2.daemon = True
              t2.start()

app = Daemonity()
daemon_runner = runner.DaemonRunner(app)
daemon_runner.do_action()
```

Comment: This code leaves processes in a zombie state and will hang if count is large enough to fill the stdout pipe. Use Popen.communicate in the thread and also put the while loop in the thread.

Comment: I had that, my_function()  is just an example, I'm only interested on how use threadings

Comment: There's nothing particularly inelegant about the code except how you monitor and relaunch threads. This kind of thing can be done with a queue and worker threads. Your main thread can wait on the queue instead of sleeping and polling.